# Display of current and past actions threw text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So iv set up a set of text to display the last actions you'v done within my game. Iv managed to get it to add the text below the current text, but how would i move all of the previous text upwards so each time it adds a new text it will place it in the same spot and only move the previous text, then delete the oldest text after a certain amount has been displayed

This is the game
http://www.fastswf.com/F7ei81E

this is the code im currently using

```
    protected function createEventText()
    {
        chatScreen = new Sprite();
        chatScreen.x = 280;
        chatScreen.y = 520;
        addChild(chatScreen);

        addText("The world has spawned!");

    }



    public function addText(t:String)
    {
        eventArray.push(t);
        for (var i:int = eventArray.length - 1; i < eventArray.length; i++)
        {
            et = new EventTextMC();
            et.txt.text = String(eventArray[i]);
            et.y = i * 20;
            chatScreen.addChild(et);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is that you keep a finite number of `EventTextMC` instances on your `chatScreen`. Then, when you add the text, you can "push" the text from the top field to the bottom field.

```
private var _historyLength:int = 5; // number of text fields to generate
private var _textFields:Array = []; // array to keep track of textfields

// create the finite number of fields (based on historyLength)
private function initLog():void 
{
    // adding 5 (historyLength) text fields to the chatScreen
    for(var i:int = 0; i < historyLength;i++)
    {
        var et:EventTextMC = new EventTextMC();
        et.y = i * 20;
        textFields.push(et);
        chatScreen.addChild(et);
    }
}

public function addText(t:String)
{
    eventArray.push(t); // this array isn't actually being used in this example

    // starting with the last text field, copy the previous field's text
    // this will create a "pushing down" effect
    // CLARIFICATION:
    // The text from the second to last field will be placed into the last field.
    // The text from the third to last field will be placed into
    // the second to last field.
    // This will continue until the text from the first field will be placed
    // in the second field, freeing up the first field for the new text.
    for(var i:int = historyLength-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        textFields[i].txt.text = textFields[i-1].txt.text;
    }
    // add the new text to the first (top-most) textfield
    textFields[0].txt.text = t;
}
```

While I'm not actually using the `eventArray` in this example, you could easily use it later on to "scroll" through the logs.

Comment: When or where do i use the initLog? Idk im slightly confused, im not sure why. Do i just have to run that once, or do i have to run it every time i run addText

Comment: You only have to run `initLog` once. I suggest you run it after you've created `chatScreen`.

Comment: Awesome! This works rly well, im confused why it works. Ill just keep re reading it untill it makes more since to me! Thanks alot tho haha

Comment: I've added more comments to try to explain it more. Please remember to mark the answer as correct, and let me know if I can explain it further.

Comment: Ty for the reminder and the extra information, that made it make allot more since ! I really appreciate your help